# Calculating percentage of pixels in polygon with specific value using Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine

I have polygons over a dataset of tree cover pixels (Hansen 2013 dataset). I calculated the total number of pixels per polygon (X) as well as the number of pixels that show tree gain (Y). This works well.

I now want to see what percentage of total pixels in the polygon show tree gain (so: Y/X *100). But I am struggling to implement this in GEE. Hope someone can help...

Some code for polygon 44 (treemask is the gain dataset):

```js
var pixels44 = treecover.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.count(),
  geometry: ID44.geometry(),
  maxPixels: 1e12
  });

var gainpixels44 = treemask.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.count(),
  geometry: ID44.geometry(),
  maxPixels: 1e12
  });
```

Comment: Wouldnt it be easier to use the histogram-reducer? That would give you the number of pixels for each value that exists inside the polygon (e.g. tree-gain, but also any other values). Then by using reduceRegions, instead of reduceRegion, you could do this for every geometry in one line.

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion... I am not sure how to translate it into code, but will use the GEE Histogram tutorial to guide me.